# How to create a stream request for Transaction history by client id on Braintree vault. NODEJS EXPRESSJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, streaming, braintree

I have been trying to create a transaction history request from Braintree using a client ID on Braintree vault, and it took far too long to figure out how, so here is the code on server that I eventually used.
Let me know if it can be improved.

Nodejs server side :

```
    exports.transaction_histroy = function(req, res) {
  if (req.user) {
      //where req.user.braintree id is the id saved on the local mongodb server.
      if (req.user.braintreeid) {
        var stream = require("stream");
        var customerStream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
          search.customerId().is(req.user.braintreeid)
        });
        res.write("[");
        var first = true;       
        customerStream.on("data", function (customer) {
          if (first) {
            first = false;
            var temp =  JSON.stringify(customer);
          } else {
            var temp =  "," + JSON.stringify(customer);
          }
          res.write(temp);
        });
        customerStream.on("end", function () {
          res.write("]");
          res.end();
        });
      }
    } else {
      res.redirect('/signin');
    }
  };
```

JQuery browser request:

```
function streamTransactions(){
$.ajax({
    url: '/users/'+user+'/transaction_histroy',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data))
        $('#transaction_histroy').append(
            data
            )
    },
    error : function(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

HTML :

```
<div id="transaction_histroy"></div>
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should have been posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/